# vbscript create-convert xml with special characters

Tags: xml, vbscript

I'm **creating** a xml file in a .vbs file with node values like the following,

```
  <car>David's</car>
  <company>Mannar & Co.</company>
```

While parsing this xml, I find issues with &, etc.

I want to convert **all possible** xml special characters with encoded characters(with **a function** or something) so that while parsing I get the original content.

Thanking you.

Comment: Hi @itsraja, I found some inaccuracy with one of the answers and proposed a fix. You probably move on by now but I am updating you as it might still be relevant (and can help others).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment of OP here i version i made myself, couldn't find a reliable one, i think it covers all possible ascii characters

```
Function HTML_Encode(byVal string)
  Dim tmp, i 
  tmp = string

  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(38), "&amp;") ' Must be the first replacement

  For i = 160 to 255
    tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(i), "&#" & i & ";")
  Next
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(34), "&quot;")
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(39), "&apos;")
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(60), "&lt;")
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(62), "&gt;")
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(32), "&nbsp;")
  HTML_Encode = tmp
End Function

Function HTML_Decode(byVal encodedstring)
  Dim tmp, i
  tmp = encodedstring
  tmp = Replace(tmp, "&quot;", chr(34) )
  tmp = Replace(tmp, "&apos;", chr(39))
  tmp = Replace(tmp, "&lt;"  , chr(60) )
  tmp = Replace(tmp, "&gt;"  , chr(62) )
  tmp = Replace(tmp, "&amp;" , chr(38) )
  tmp = Replace(tmp, "&nbsp;", chr(32) )
  For i = 160 to 255
    tmp = Replace(tmp, "&#" & i & ";", chr(i))
  Next
  HTML_Decode = tmp
End Function

str = "This !@#± is a & test!"
wscript.echo HTML_Encode(str) '=> This&nbsp;!@#&amp;#177;&nbsp;is&nbsp;a&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;test!
wscript.echo HTML_Decode(HTML_Encode(str)) '=> This !@#± is a & test!
```

Answer (score 8):

This is an old post but I am replying as I hope this will save someone some grief

I was working on an issue where a vendor complained that in some cases not all the special characters are being escaped in the XML. I was surprised to see that the **dev used it’s own logic (function)** and not some functionality offered by the framework as escaping sounds like a very common task. The following is the function before the fix:

```
Function HTML_Encode(byVal string)
  Dim tmp, i 
  tmp = string
  For i = 160 to 255
    tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(i), "&#" & i & ";")
  Next
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(34), "&quot;")
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(39), "&apos;")
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(60), "&lt;")
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(62), "&gt;")
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(38), "&amp;") <- the problem: this line should be the first replacement
  tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(32), "&nbsp;")
  HTML_Encode = tmp
End Function
```

Funny enough, it looks exactly as one of the answers to this post (probably copied from here :-).

I traced the problem to **the order which the special characters is being replaced**.  Replacing the ampersand (`&`) **MUST** be the first replacement (line) as replacements (like: `&quot;`) are injecting ampersands which in turn will be replaced by `&amp;`. For example, if I have the following string: `We <3 SO`. The original (above) function will escape it to: `We &amp;lt;3 SO`. The right escaping is: `We &lt;3 SO`.

So the revised function can be:

```
  Function HTML_Encode(byVal string)
      Dim tmp, i 
      tmp = string

      tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(38), "&amp;") <- Must be the first replacement (Thanks Aaron)

      For i = 160 to 255
        tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(i), "&#" & i & ";")
      Next

      tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(34), "&quot;")
      tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(39), "&apos;")
      tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(60), "&lt;")
      tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(62), "&gt;")
      tmp = Replace(tmp, chr(32), "&nbsp;")
      HTML_Encode = tmp
    End Function
```

For completeness, you can find the Predefined entities in XML [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)

Answer (score 0):

My keys weren't cold yet when i did found another one, i give this as another answer because the output is slichtly different, so you can choose which suits best. I did remove the original answer to not confuse

```
Function Escape(s) 
  Dim scr
  Set scr = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
  scr.Language = "VBScript"
  scr.Reset
  Escape = scr.Eval("escape(""" & s & """)")
End Function

Function Unescape(s)
  Dim scr
  Set scr = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
  scr.Language = "VBScript"
  scr.Reset
  Unescape = scr.Eval("unescape(""" & s & """)")
End Function

wscript.echo Escape("This !@#± is a & test!") '=> This%20%21@%23%B1%20is%20a%20%26%20test%21
wscript.echo Unescape(Escape("This !@#± is a & test!")) '=> This !@#± is a & test!
```