# How to write special characters as they are to XML file

Tags: xml, vbscript, qtp

I am trying to create files based on the data provided in excel using vbscript/QTP. The problem I have is with negative testcases having special characters. I want to write special characters as node text but they are getting auto converted to escape characters.

**Text to be written** : address line one is<>"'&amp equal to 3
**Actual Text after saving the file**: address line one is&lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp equal to 3

Is there any way to tell vbscript/XMLDOM not to convert these.

Code I am using is simple one.

```
Set  NodeList = uxtXMLDoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode(strNodePath)

If  Not(NodeList is Nothing) Then                                       
    NodeList.childNodes(0).nodeValue = "address line one is&lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp equal to 3"
End If
```

Comment: **text to be written field** has converted the special characters already.  :)However you can find the actual text to be written in the code part.

Comment: < and > are what defines an attribute in xml, you can not use them as value without escaping it hence it will be considered a attribute. When you read the XML you should get the text in the format you expect. (Without escape characters).. What is the problem you are having ?

Comment: I am trying to input the escape characters only. Please refer my code.
What issue I am facing is every ampersand is getting converted to '&amp;'  and hence, characters like '&gt;' and not coming as expected in my resultant MQ message which is reading this XML.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following line inside the 'If' condition:

```
NodeList.childNodes(0).nodeValue = "address line one is"&Chr(60)&Chr(62)&Chr(34)&chr(39)&"&amp equal to 3"
```

Here,

```
  chr(60) means <
  chr(62) means >
  chr(34) means "
  chr(39) means '
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Not exactly the issue I have.

The issue I have is.... even if I try to add an (&lt;) or (&gt;) escape characters, vbscript is changing it to (&amp;lt) or (&amp;gt) hence my xml is getting incorrect characters.

If  Not(NodeList is Nothing) Then                                       
    NodeList.childNodes(0).nodeValue = "address line one is&lt;&gt;&quot;&apos;&amp equal to 3"
End If

















Resultant xml 
<Order1>
       <Name>address line one is&amp;lt;&amp;gt;&amp;quot;&amp;apos;&amp equal to 3</Name>
</Order>

Answer (score 0):

With the use of @Kira 's solution and solutions posted at the below link I was able to create my solution. The issue is that XML replaces linearly from start to end.

```
Hence first ampersand in ("&lt;") will be replaced as ("&amp;lt") instead of (<).
```

You have to proactively replace the characters before XML replaces them.

```
strReplaceText = Replace(strtext, "&lt;", chr(60)) //Sample... Repeat for all the chars
NodeList.childNodes(0).nodeValue = strReplaceText 
objXML.Save(destination)
```

For more info, visit this thread.
[vbscript create-convert xml with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899151/vbscript-create-convert-xml-with-special-characters)